# I created the [microsoft-flow] tag and want to check with the community

Tags: discussion, support

So I have asked a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52740289/check-a-date-field-is-blank-or-empty-in-ms-flow-expression) about **Microsoft Flow**, and **specifically about using expressions** in MS Flow...

as there doesn't appear to be a tag specific to *expressions* in MS Flow, I ended up creating one...

If I am wrong, can someone please point me in the right direction?

I understand that everyone might be offended by my downright arrogance and temerity in daring to create a new tag, but alongside the flood of downvotes meaning *disagree* please could someone tell me the right approach when a tag appears to be missing?

Also, if that tag is approved by the tag team, shall I complete a new *tag wiki*?

Comment: There's no such thing as _the tag team_. If you're confident the tag is appropriate and on-topic, you should go ahead and suggest an excerpt and a wiki. It seems you've put some thought into it, so I'd say it's appropriate. Newly created tags are visible in the 10K tools under _New tags_, so there's no need for you to raise this on meta, unless there are specific concerns about this tag you want to discuss.